# Python: function default input that stands for everything

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a variable in python that stands for everything?

I have a function called filter:

```
def filter(df, col1 = ?, col2 = ?, col3 = ?):
     return df.loc[(df.col1 == col1) & (df.col2 == col2) & (df.col3 = col3),:]
```

## What should ? be?

=====================

Desired output:

if the code is filter(df), then the program returns the entire data frame.

if the code is filter(df, col1 = 'N'), then the program returns a sub data frame where the values in col1 = 'N'. (ignore the constraints for col2 and col3)

if the code is filter(df, col1 = 'N', col3 = 'S'), then the program returns a sub data frame where the values in col1 = 'N' and col3 = 'S'. (ignore the constraints for col2)

=====================

Is there an easy way to do it instead of multiple if-statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a more elegant way, but off the top of my head, you could use something like:

```
def my_filter(df, **kwargs):
    for column in kwargs:
        filter_value = kwargs[column]
        df = df.loc[df[column] == filter_value, ]
    return df

filtered_df = my_filter(df, col1='N', col2='S')
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I learned sth new! I didn't know **kwargs before!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of data you have in these columns you could do something like this:

```
def filter(df, col1s='', col2s='', col3s=''):
     return df.loc[df.col1.str.contains(col1s) & df.col2.str.contains(col2s) & df.col3.str.contains(col3s)]
```

Starting with a default arg of an empty string, which when passed to `.str.contains()` will return anything, you won't filter on those columns which aren't provided.

This of course assumes that using `str.contains()` will return the same sample from your data that `==` would.  (Guessing off of your `'N', 'S'` 1 length strings it would, but if theres anything even slightly more complex there we'll have to explore other options).

Comment: That's really helpful! The data are all length 1 strings!